# update text area with modified date

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I have a form with input fields and textarea field.I'm submitting that form after user enter information and it works fine.I'm updating that form and I can update the data into DB as well.my problem is I want to add date to textarea field if user add any new comments in text area.when I click on update button data should update with date and that date should display along with the comments.my problem is how to add date if user changed text area? can any body pls help me to do that?

```
<form name=frmSubmit action="edit.php?id={$activeTaskID}" method=POST  enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <input type='hidden' name='form' value='profile'/>
                        <fieldset style="width:48%; float:left;">
                            <label>Task Title</label>
                            <input name="taskTitle" id="bugTitle" type="text" style="width:94%" value="{$taskData->taskTitle}"/>                    
                        </fieldset>
                        <fieldset style="width:48%; float:right;">
                            <label>Category</label>
                            <select name="categoryID_FK" id="categoryID_FK" class="textbox"  >
                                {$catOptions}
                            </select>       
                        </fieldset>
                        <fieldset style="width:48%; float:right; ">
                            <label>Assign Employee</label>
                            <div style="margin-left:3%;margin-top: 5%;">{$options}</div>
                        </fieldset>
                        <fieldset  style="width:48%; float:left;%">
                            <label>Task Details</label>
                            <textarea name=taskDescn id=taskDescn rows=25 style="width:94%">{$taskData->taskDescn}</textarea>
                        </fieldset>

                        <fieldset style="width:48%; float:right;">
                            <label>Priority</label>
                            <select name="priority" class="textbox"  >
                                {$priorityOptions}
                            </select>       
                        </fieldset>
                        <fieldset style="width:48%; float:right;">
                            <label>Due Date</label><br/>
                             <input type="text" id="datepicker" name="dueDate" value="{$taskData->dueDate}" style="width:88%"/>
                            <script>
                              $(function() {
                                $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
                                  showOn: "button",
                                  buttonImage: "images/calendar.gif",
                                  buttonImageOnly: true,
                                  dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
                                });
                              });
                              </script>
                              <style>
                                .ui-datepicker-trigger {margin-top:13px;}
                              </style>
                              <label style="margin-top:2px">Time</label><br/>
                             <input type="text" id="picktime" name="dueTime" class="time" value="{$taskData->dueTime}" style="width:88%"/>
                             <script>
                              $(function() {
                                $('#picktime').timepicker();
                              });
                              </script>
                        </fieldset> 
                        <fieldset style="width:48%; float:right;">
                            <label>Attachment</label>
                            <input name="attachment" id="attachment" type="file"/><br/>
                            {$taskAttachmentStr}
                        </fieldset> 

                    </form> 
                        <div class="clear">
                    </div>
                </div>


                <div class="submit_link">       
                                    <input type="submit" class="alt_btn" value='Update Task' onclick="document.forms['frmSubmit'].submit();" />
                </div>
</form>


$p = & $_POST;

    if ( isset($p['form'])  && $p['form'] == 'profile' )
    {




 $query = "UPDATE tasks SET ".
                        "taskTitle =  '". $p['taskTitle'] ."', ".
                        "taskDescn =  '". $p['taskDescn'] ."' , ".
                        "dueDate   =  '". $p['dueDate'] ."', ".
                        "categoryID_FK   =  '". $['categoryID_FK'] ."', ".
                              "priority =  '". $p['priority'] ."'
                        WHERE taskID_PK =  '". $activeTaskID ."'
                        ";
            $sqlObj = new db_connect();
            $sqlObj->fetch($query);
    }
```

Comment: It would help if you post your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your textarea, you can use this code to add date when user clicks in it. User types something and submits the form, which posts contents of textarea (along with the date):

```
$("#taskDescn").click(function() {
    // get today's date after formatting properly and add below
    $(this).html("04/07/2014: ");
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NUtcj/1/)

Comment: thanks.but it updates only the date not the contents.i want contents+date

Comment: So instead of adding date at the beginning (which my snippet does) you want date to appear at the end of textarea contents? Please explain with clarity.

Answer (score 0):

(Below code is only a prototype and not a working piece of code)

**for textbox:**    You can try onchange() function in javascript.

**For the data you want with date:** Get the value of textbox using textBoxName.Value() and then return string in javascript as follows:
        return getDate() + textBoxName.Value()